# Adding an object into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following object:

```
{
  "EekvB3cnwEzE":{
     "name":"hi",
  },
  "Brv1R4C6bZnD":{
     "name":"yup",
  },
  "kRwRXju6ALJZ":{
     "name":"okay",
  }
}
```

I am trying to add each of these items into an array. I do the following code but for some reason, I get back `[]` in my `console.log`

Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

```
$scope.items = [];

$http.get("/url").success(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) { $scope.items[key] = value; });
    console.log($scope.items);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Named keys will be ignored when you log an array.

If you want them to show up there, you'll need to replace `key` (in this bit of code `$scope.items[key]`) with a number or use a `.push(value)` instead of an assignment.

Comment: I'd like to have my array index still be the "key" because I want to be able to search for them by key. is there no way to do this in javascript?

Comment: @bryan An "array" with named indexes is an object, which you already have in the first place.

Comment: @bryan — The point of an array is to have an ordered list of things. That order is described by the property names, which are numbers. If you want named keys, use a plain object (like the thing you appear to be copying the values from) instead of an array.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Thank you both for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your ajax call. Because the following works:

```
var x = [];
$.each({
  "EekvB3cnwEzE":{
     "name":"hi",
  },
  "Brv1R4C6bZnD":{
     "name":"yup",
  },
  "kRwRXju6ALJZ":{
     "name":"okay",
  }
}, function(key, value){
    x[key] = value;
});
console.log(x);
```

It will log:

```
[EekvB3cnwEzE: Object, Brv1R4C6bZnD: Object, kRwRXju6ALJZ: Object]
```

Comment: When I do `console.log(key, value);` I get back each item in the JSON. So I don't think there is anything wrong with my ajax call.